# How to save/load different Settings in QML only?

Tags: qt, qml

I have the following code where I am trying to save/load different values for my QML application.

```
Settings {
    id: laserControlSettings
    fileName : "test.ini" // this might change, as ther emight be more than one possible setting
    property var laserStepValue
}

SettingsBar {
    id : settingBar
    FileDialog {
        id: fileDialog
        title : "Choose INI File"
        nameFilters : "*.ini"
        currentFolder: // WHAT TO PUT HERE?
        onAccepted:{
            //WHAT TO DO HERE?
        }
    }

    onSaveSettingsButtonClicked :
    {
        laserControlSettings.laserStepValue = laserStepEntry.value;
        laserControlSettings.sync();
    }

    onLoadSettingsButtonClicked :
    {
        fileDialog.open();
    }
}

SpinBox {
    id: laserStepEntry
}
```

I don't know how to set up my fileDialog to read the appropriate ini file to load and apply to my spinBox. How should I do this?

Is this the right way to use Settings? I also want the user to be able to save different settings.

For example, the user could have a "LowIntensitySetting.ini", which would have the value at 0, and a "HighIntensitySetting.ini" which would have a value of 100. This would all be chosen by the user of course.

Comment: In my opinion,, the point about `Settings` is to persist settings between runs of an application. The built in `Settings` object is pre-initialize to defaults for your app, so, you shouldn't need UI to configure it. What you're doing, prompting the user for load/save is no different than any other document, so, technically it isn't Settings. In fact, if that is the case, I would favour JSON over the settings, since with JSON you can store more interested typed information.

Comment: I would probably move the detail of file format etc to C++, and expose the data to QML as model.